# How read a single byte data from log which is in hex using python?

Tags: python

Here is the code used to read data and log in a file

I have logged a log using this python code, I am able to retrieve the serial data correctly in log but i need to get this read data in single byte after every dlc byte

```
import serial,os,binascii
import time
import codecs
from datetime import datetime


now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%d%m%Y--%H%M%S")
print("date and time:", date_time)
file_name = str(date_time)+"_data_log"
print(file_name)
file1 = open(file_name + '.txt', 'a')

data_List = []
def flatlist(l):
    for x in l:
        if type(x) == list:
            flatlist(x)
        else:
            data_List.append(x)

try:
    serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM3" , baudrate= 57600, bytesize=8, timeout= 1, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    serialString = ""
    print(os.getcwd())
    data_serial = []
    value=0
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
            #data = serialPort.read_all()
            #print(data)
            data =serialPort.read(40)
            #print(data1)
            data_serial = data.hex(' ')
            print(str(now)+ "    :  " + data_serial + " ")
            file1.write(str(now)+ "    :  " + str(data_serial)+" \n ")
            file1.flush()

except serial.SerialException as e:
    if e.errno == 13:
        
        raise e
    pass
```

Comment: Why are you busy looping on `serialPort.in_waiting > 0`?  Why not just read the data and let it block?  Including `flatlist` seems unnecessary as it's unreferenced, why include it?